# Proving that $f(x) \le\ g(x)$, for all $x \in\ [c,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions which are differentiable on $(a,b)$ with

$$f(c) = g(c)$$
for some $c\in (a,b)$.

If
$$ f'(x) \le\ g'(x),\qquad \forall \;x \in [c,b)
$$
prove that
$$
f(x) \le g(x),\qquad \forall \;x \in [c,b)
$$

We are not allowed to use Riemann Integrals. However since $$f'(x) \le g'(x)$$ 
We can state that g - f is increasing. This is where I'm lost.

Comment: What if $f'$ or $g'$ is not Riemann integrable?

Comment: @UmbertoP. It is not Riemann integrable. The following lecture goes over Riemann Integrals. We haven't learned it yet. The classwork is very strict to the lecture

Comment: Sorry, that comment should have been directed at @rightskewed. You can't recover $f$ from its derivative without some extra conditions.

Comment: Consider the function $h(x):=g(x)-f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

You have that $g' - f' \ge 0$ on $(c,b)$ so that $g-f$ is nondecreasing. Thus $x \in (c,b)$ will satisfy $$g(x) - f(x) \ge g(c) - f(c) = 0$$ so that $f(x) \le g(x)$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better not to finish off the proof?

Comment: In my opinion the question should be marked for closure. Hence a complete answer is preferable, I'd say...

Comment: Couldn't believe I missed that. Sometimes it's the little stupid things. However wouldn't it be g'(x) - f'(x) < 0?

Answer (score 0):

We have  $\forall x\in\left[c,b\right)$
 $$\int_{c}^{x}f'\left(t\right)dt\leq\int_{c}^{x}g'\left(t\right)dt$$
 then by fundamental theorem of calculus $$f\left(x\right)-f\left(c\right)\leq g\left(x\right)-g\left(c\right)$$
  then the thesis using $f\left(c\right)=g\left(c\right).$